# Would I get promoted to upper league with the new MMR system by this playing frequency?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was in master 4v4 (Random) a while ago. I did not play for 1 season and when I get back I got placed in bronze league. Games were too easy for me now but the thing is: I play 1 day  a week (~10 games) and I win most of them. I only got to silver first day. 2 weeks later gold. And now I have played more than 10 games in gold and I won most of them but still I'm in gold. I know as the time passes my MMR decays but will I be able to get into higher leagues by playing in this frequency? once a week?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, MMR does not decay. Do you have a source on that?

Comment: Well I heard it from [Husky](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CCj_CwCDls&feature=share&list=PLooJOgo-8bTqAl25k0tfIPPAw86P91Se-&index=1). Jump to minute 2:00 please. There's also [Blizz](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/10025152690).

Comment: @OrcJMR MMR definitely decays in SC2

Comment: @Decency Yup, I see that already. I've last played over a year ago - either it was not the case then, or was not yet found out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Blizzard Forums](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/10025152690):

By not playing for an entire season, you wiped your MMR clean.

> If you are inactive for an entire season (that is, you stop playing in
>   Season n, you play no games--ranked or unranked--during Season n+1,
>   you come back for Season n+2), your MMR is wiped clean.

Therefore it will take sometime to get to upper leagues. Just keep playing, you eventually will end up where you belong according to your MMR.

For answering your question:

> **How Frequently Must I Keep Playing to Prevent Decay?**
>
> Decay begins to take effect between 2 weeks and 4 weeks of
>   uninterrupted inactivity. We believe the effect to be linear, from a
>   decay of 0 at 2 weeks to about 310 at 4 weeks. The below image
>   illustrates:
>   [image: hypothesized graph of loss of MMR]
>   The red line is the decay rate. x is time in days and y is decay amount. The decay hard caps at the blue and green lines.

So, you're safe playing one day a week. Your MMR won't decay.

Comment: even playing once every 2 weeks will keep your mmr up

Comment: This is assuming that the system works correctly and how they say it does.  From my own experience, right now it takes LOAAAAAAAAAAAAADS of games to get promoted.  This is probably more due to the fact that they're more cautious about promotions now that they've disabled mid-season demotions.  As an example, a 14x master league player (1v1) it took me roughly 125 games (~100-25) to promote into master after resetting my MMR.

Comment: I can confirm that. 27-5 and still gold. Now I'm getting comfortable and having fun crushing my opponents but when I get higher I'll probably stress out:)

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli I got promoted from gold to platinum right around that mark.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends 38-6 and finally platinum..